# Is there such thing as an active-low, logic level mosfet?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic

I need to make a logic level switch that will turn on when the input signal is 0V (active low). I figured using a MOSFET is the best way to go, but I'm not so sure if there are active low MOSFETS.

Comment: To get best answers you need to specify as many parameters as possible. eg What voltage are you using? Any current requirements? ...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *I need to make a logic level switch that will turn on when the input
>   signal is 0V (active low)*

You can use a suitable P channel MOSFET for this: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.baldengineer.com/low-side-vs-high-side-transistor-switch.html).

So, if the logic input is high, the P channel MOSFET is turned off and the load is disconnected from the +5 volts supply. If the logic input is low then the MOSFET activates and the load is connected to the 5 volt supply.

You can also use logic level analogue switches but watch out for limitations in on-resistance however, if you require really low leakage current (device deactivated) then an analogue switch will probably be better than a single MOSFET in many circumstances. ADG802 Example: -

[image]

The above has an on-resistance of 0.25 ohm and operates from 1.8 volts to 5.5 volts. All the usual vendors (TI, Maxim etc.) will have equivalent versions of this device.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a P-channel FET if the voltage you are switching is not higher than the input voltage (or voltage tolerance).

Or you can use two FETs. The first one would drive the second one low, when input is high. Pull up resistor on the second one will limit the gate current, which might become a problem on high loads.

Or you could use a JFET if the above won't solve the problem.